# No logro guardar variable de sesion

Tags: php

Tengo mi archivo index.php de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'controllers/loginController.php';
$login=new LoginController();
//obtengo array actual
$token=$login->tokenActual();


$respuesta=json_decode($token);
//obtengo informacion del login 0: no existe sesion; 1:token existente
$estado = $respuesta->exito;

if ($estado === 0){
    $payload = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $data=json_decode($payload);
    
    $usuario=$data->user;
    $contraseña=$data->password;
    

    $array=$login->crearToken($usuario,$contraseña);
   
    echo $array;
}
$jwt='';
if ($estado === 1){
    $jwt = $respuesta->data;

}

if ($jwt===$_SESSION['token']){
  
$routesArray = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$routesArray= array_filter($routesArray);

if (count($routesArray)==0){
    $json = array(

        'status'=>404,
        'result'=>'not found'

    );
    
    echo json_encode($json, http_response_code($json['status']));
}else{
    require_once('controllers/' . $routesArray[3] . 'Controller.php');


      switch($routesArray[3]){
      case 'articulo':
  
        $controllerArticulo = new articuloController();
        switch ($routesArray[4]){
            case 'index':
               
               $array=$controllerArticulo->listarTodos();
                echo json_encode($array);
                break;
           
        
                                }
      
}
}
}
else{
 
}
?>
```

como veran llamo a tokenActual, que me devuelve si existe un token:

```
public function tokenActual(){
    
        if (!isset($_SESSION["token"])){
            return json_encode(
                array(
                    "mensaje" => "No existe sesion actual",
                    "data" => '',
                    "exito" =>0,
                ));
        }
        else{
            return json_encode(
                array(
                    "mensaje" => "Token existente",
                    "data" => $_SESSION["token"],
                    "exito" =>1,
                ));
        }
       
    }
```

El caso es que haciendo **var_dump($token);** obtengo: "No existe sesion actual" como que no hay nada guardado en la sesion, pero la aplicacion pasa el formulario de login:

```
   public function crearToken($nombreusuario,$contraseña){
       $usuario=loginController::existeUsuario($nombreusuario,$contraseña);
     

           if (count($usuario)>0){
          
               $nombre = $nombreusuario;
           
               $secret_key = "OLAh6Yh5KwNFvOqgltw7";
               $issuer_claim = "localhost";
               $audience_claim = "THE_AUDIENCE";
               $issuedat_claim = time(); 
           
               $notbefore_claim = $issuedat_claim + 10; //not before in seconds
               $expire_claim = $issuedat_claim + 60; // expire time in seconds
               $token = array(
                   "iss" => $issuer_claim,
                   "aud" => $audience_claim,
                   "iat" => $issuedat_claim,
                   "nbf" => $notbefore_claim,
                   "exp" => $expire_claim,
                   "data" => array(
                      
                       "firstname" => $nombre,
                      
               ));

               http_response_code(200);

               $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $secret_key);
              
               $_SESSION["token"] = $jwt;
         
               return json_encode(
                   array(
                       "mensaje" => "Logueado satisfactoriamente",
                       "data" => $jwt,
                       "exito" =>1
                       //"expireAt" => $expire_claim
                   ));
               }
                   else{

                   http_response_code(401);
                   return json_encode(array("message" => "Login failed.", "password" => $contraseña));
                   }

       
               }       
}
```

Es decir se crea el token pero no entiendo porque no lo guarda en la $_SESSION

Comment: Intenta a ver si funciona añadir ```session_start()``` en la función *crearToken*

Comment: Acabo de probar e ignora la instrucción dado que ya tengo session_start() en el archivo index.php

Comment: Si había visto que tienes```session_start``` al inicio, y después instancias la clase *loginController*, pero por probar. ¿Y si creas alguna sesión manualmente fuera del código, tampoco lo crea o persiste el mismo error?